# Hide UIActionSheet on iPad

Tags: ipad, uiactionsheet

I just got a mail from apple that my iPad app was rejected because my 'app contains popover elements that didn't point  to the element that revealed them and more than one popover element visible onscreen at a time'.

The problem is that I call an actionsheet which is still visible when I switch from one view to another and that there can be called to actionsheets at a time. 
Now I ask myself how I can hide an actionsheet on a view change or when another actionsheet is opend.

Comment: Ok now I handled it that the actionsheet hides when I switch the view with [myActionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO]; But I don't know how to avoid that that the ActionSheet opens mutiple times when I click the button to call the ActionSheet

Comment: I tried to work with myActionSheet.visible. But it won't work. When I log myActionSheet.visible I always get null.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue with the sheet showing multiple times when you tap the same button by checking `isVisible`, as in the following:

```
- (IBAction) btnFoo: (id) sender
{
    if ([self.sheet isVisible]) {
        [self.sheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:self.sheet.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];
        return;
    }

    [self.sheet showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
}
```

Hope that helps.